Why do ruby http libraries result in unexpected character encodings? (curb, excon vs shell-out)
I'm getting response bodies from external request libraries (curb, excon) as ascii-8bit, where I'm expecting utf-8.
My ruby environment is set up for utf-8 encoding by default:
Encoding.default_external
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
Encoding.default_internal
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>

I can't reveal the url or (obviously) auth tokens in this request, but I get a valid utf-8 response if I shell out to curl:
text = `curl -H "Authorization: Bearer #{token}" "#{url}"`
text[28782..28786]
=> "Maté,"
text.encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>

But if I use any of the ruby libs, I get a different result
curb:
curl = Curl::Easy.new(url)
curl.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer #{client.auth_token}"
curl.http_get
body = curl.body_str
body[28782..28786]
=> "Mat\xC3\xA9"
body.encoding
=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>

excon:
connection = Excon.new(url, headers: {"Authorization" => "Bearer #{token}"})
response = connection.get
response_body = response.body
response_body[28782..28786]
=> "Mat\xC3\xA9"
response_body.encoding
=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>

This is causing issues when saving response data to other external services. I know in this case I could simply slap a force_encoding("utf-8") onto the end of my call, but this seems like a band-aid. So my question is: how does the response of these http libraries get interpreted as ascii-8bit, and how can I change that systemically?

What encoding does the server actually use when returning content?

Can you provide relevant versions? e.g. Ruby version, Curb version, and/or Excon version?

sorry to hear you are having issues here. I'm the primary developer and maintainer of excon, so I can at least speak to that part of your question.
HTTP/1.1 is oriented around byte counting in many cases, so using ascii was the easy way to do that without needing to worry about multi-byte characters and things.
That being said, if you are confident that the response is UTF-8 (a good indication would be if the content-type header says so), I think it should be safe/reasonable to force it into "UTF-8" encoding. I suspect that is what I would do in this situation, or at least that it is worth a shot.
Are there particular concerns you have about this that make you feel like it would be a band-aid or otherwise not be a reasonable longer term solution?

Thanks! Ultimately this is what we're ending up doing; while in parallel trying to open up a thread with the vendor in question. The response headers I'm seeing say ContentType: text/plain with no charset specified; yet in some cases we are clearly getting utf-8 (compatible) encodings. In this case I'm no longer convinced it's a band-aid as it seems that's as much as can be directly inferred from the response. (Still it's interesting that I get utf-8 from curl shellout, but maybe that's just an artifact of shelling out in any case)

Oof, yeah. I wish that http was nicer and more consistent. Unfortunately many servers do things slightly differently, and it's the same story on the client side.
I think that force_encoding should be pretty safe overall (or at least I'm not aware of negative side effects). So although it seems a bit weird and potentially unsafe, I suspect you should probably be fine doing it.
